# Storing calculated field in a Form for use in a Report

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2016

I wanted to store a Form calculated field somewhere so I can use it in a Report.

I understand that it is not recommended to store calculated fields in tables because it breaks rules of normalization.

My DB is basically a simple sum of debits, the sum of credits, and the sum of spendings for many small projects which I want to print a report of at the end of each month. These fields are SUMS so they are calculated fields and the Profit is calculated using [sum of credits]-[sum of spendings].

Should I calculate the Proft field in the Form and store it in the table which the Report is based on. Or should I change my DB design and how would I lay it out?

Comment: Why don't you calculate in query and use query as source for report? Or even use report Sorting & Grouping feature with aggregate calcs in textbox? This allows display of detail data as well as summary calcs.

Comment: I am not an expert in DB design nor ms-access, you might have noticed from my very primitive approach and the solution that I have found. Thanks for the insights you've mentioned. I will look into learning those tactics for future use.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I can do this very easily using the report wizard. I only needed to include both `projects` table and individual `transactions` (main Form and its Subform) in the report so a query would be generated.

In the report wizard, there is an option to present summaries of results and one could choose the kind of data summary that needs to be presented. I just chose the sum of the fields of debit, credit, and spending. This option is on the reports wizard Sorting windows under *Summary Option ...*.

When I go into the Design View of the Report, I can rearrange the fields and hide the sections as I need so I would get a one-line summary for each record.